# My Heart Rate Calc wont run all the way through for some reason

Tags: c, debugging

This is what I get as my output:

```
Please enter your birthday month MM:11

Please enter your birthday day DD:12

Please enter your birthday year YYYY:1997

Please enter the current month MM:08

Please enter the current day DD:12

Please enter the current year YYYY:2020

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why does it finish the process and exits without calculating age and printing the rest of the stuff?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// maximum heart rate in beats per minute is 220 minus your age in years.
// Your target heart rate is a range that’s 50–85% of your maximum heart rate.
// Create a program that reads the user’s birthday and the current day
// (each consisting of the month, day and year).
// Your program should calculate and display the person’s age
// (in years), the person’s maximum heart rate and the person’s target-heart-rate range.

int main() {
    // Variables to hold birthdate values
    int birthMonth;
    int birthDay;
    int birthYear;
    // Variables to hold current date values
    int curMonth;
    int curDay;
    int curYear;
    // Explains program functionality to user
    printf("This program will take your birth date and the current date and output your age, maximum heart rate, and target heart rate.\n");

    // Typical prompt / storage
    printf("Please enter your birthday month MM: ");
    scanf("%d", &birthMonth);

    printf("\nPlease enter your birthday day DD: ");
    scanf("%d", &birthDay);

    printf("\nPlease enter your birthday year YYYY: ");
    scanf("%d", &birthYear);

    printf("\nPlease enter the current month MM: ");
    scanf("%d", &curMonth);

    printf("\nPlease enter the current day DD: ");
    scanf("%d", &curDay);

    printf("\nPlease enter the current year YYYY: ");
    scanf("%d", &curYear);

    int age = curYear - birthYear;                  // Calculates age, if statements do rest
    int maxHeartRate = 220-age;                     // Calculates heart rate based on age
    int lowTarHeartRate = maxHeartRate*.5;          // Calculates lower end target heart rate
    int highTarHeartRate = maxHeartRate*.85;        // Calculates higher end target heart rate

    // If current month is after birth month, we know the age, and will print.
    if (curMonth>birthMonth){
        printf("\nYou are %d\nYourYour Maximum Heart Rate is %d\nYour Target Heart Rate is %d-%d\n", age,maxHeartRate, lowTarHeartRate, highTarHeartRate);
    }
        // If the current month is the same as the birth month, we need further checks
    else if (curMonth == birthMonth) {
        if (curDay > birthDay || curDay == birthDay) {
            printf("\nYou are %d\nYour Maximum Heart Rate is %d\nYour Target Heart Rate is %d-%d\n", age, maxHeartRate, lowTarHeartRate, highTarHeartRate);
        }
        // If the current day is within the same month but before the birth day, age adjust
        else {
            age = age-1;              // Refactoring age
            maxHeartRate = 220-age;   // Refactoring maximum heart rate with new age value

            printf("\nYou are %d\nYour Maximum Heart Rate is %d\nYour Target Heart Rate is %d-%d\n", age, maxHeartRate, lowTarHeartRate, highTarHeartRate);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if both `curMonth>birthMonth` and `curMonth == birthMonth` are false (which will happen with `curMonth == 8` and `birthMonth == 11`)? I suggest you step through your code statement by statement in a debugger to see what really happens.

Answer (score 0):

> "*Why does it finish the process and exits without calculating age and printing the rest of the stuff?*"

Because in your code you missing the case, when `curMonth < birthMonth`, which is indeed the case with your input (`birthMonth = 11` and `curMonth = 8`).

You only check for `curMonth > birthMonth` 1. and `curMonth == birthMonth` 2..

---

Implement another `else` or `else if (curMonth < birthMonth)` (if you plan to add another alternative):

```
// If current month is after birth month, we know the age, and will print.
if (curMonth>birthMonth){
    printf("\nYou are %d\nYourYour Maximum Heart Rate is %d\nYour Target Heart Rate is %d-%d\n", age,maxHeartRate, lowTarHeartRate, highTarHeartRate);
}

// If the current month is the same as the birth month, we need further checks
else if (curMonth == birthMonth) {
    if (curDay > birthDay || curDay == birthDay) {
        printf("\nYou are %d\nYour Maximum Heart Rate is %d\nYour Target Heart Rate is %d-%d\n", age, maxHeartRate, lowTarHeartRate, highTarHeartRate);
    }
    // If the current day is within the same month but before the birth day, age adjust
    else {
        age = age-1;              // Refactoring age
        maxHeartRate = 220-age;   // Refactoring maximum heart rate with new age value

        printf("\nYou are %d\nYour Maximum Heart Rate is %d\nYour Target Heart Rate is %d-%d\n", age, maxHeartRate, lowTarHeartRate, highTarHeartRate);
    }
}

// If the current month is before birth month.
else { // if curMonth < birthMonth                             <--------- HERE
        ....
}
```